# Using Spring EL to decide which outbound gateway to use

Tags: spring, http, expression, gateway

My application can use one of two web services, lets call them WS A and WS B. Both contain the same interface.

I want to perform some logic on the HTTP headers and request channel. WS B should only used on certain request channels. To decide which channel is used I have created a Java class that takes the request channel as a String parameter.

```
<http:outbound-gateway request-channel="XXXXX"
        url-expression="'${EL EXP}'" http-method="GET"
        extract-request-payload="true" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="3000" reply-channel="XXXXX">
    </http:outbound-gateway>
```

I then read that the url-expression is evaluated when the context is initialised.

source : http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?113446-Usage-of-expressions-in-http-namespace-element-url

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway  request-channel="requestChannel"
        url="dummy"
        http-method="GET" extract-request-payload="true" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="3000" reply-channel="sysLoggerRequestChannel"> 
          <int-http:uri-variable name="teststring" expression="test"/>
          <int-http:uri-variable name="url" expression="evalClass.getDestinationForChannel(teststring)"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

The problem with this approach is that the expressions in int-http:uri-variable do not seem to be evaluation.

All this makes me believe I am taking the wrong approach. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You have your expression above enclosed in single quotes. In that case SpEL will treat your expression as a literal string. Could be that is all that is tripping you up with this approach. Either way, I think using a Router would be a better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate web service end points and a way to determine which one to use per message then a Spring Integration [router](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#router) would be better suited to directing your messages around. This has the added advantage that you can do further processing on your messages specific to the endpoint prior to sending.

There are many many ways to configure a router, including writing an entirely custom one, so I suggest reading through that whole section to see what will work best for you.

A quick example based on message type:

```
<int:payload-type-router input-channel="requests">
   <int:mapping type="my.business.WebServiceARequest" channel="wsA" />
   <int:mapping type="my.business.WebServiceBRequest" channel="wsB" />
</int:payload-type-router>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="wsA" url="http://wsA.com/whatever" 
     ... />
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="wsB" url="http://wsB.com/foo" 
     ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a Spring Bean you should use `@`. So instead of `expression="evalClass.getDestinationForChannel(teststring)"` it will be `expression="@evalClass.getDestinationForChannel(teststring)"`.